# Gmail Primary Tab IMAP

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-imap

I want to get the contents of the "Primary" tab in Gmail using IMAP (in node.js using node-imap)

I can easily get the Important folder, but I can't get the Primary folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question was already asked on the webapps site: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/can-i-see-my-gmail-inbox-tabs-as-imap-labels

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not currently possible.

If you search the [Google dev site](https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=tabs+gmail+imap), nothing comes up.

Specifically, there's nothing about tabs on Google's [IMAP Extensions page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions).